# How can I use React Router production in a static web context ?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

Is that possible to use a React-Router (V4) based app, hosted in a static environment such as Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Yes Possible!**

Within the [README](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) of an app created with create-react-app, there are a number of helpful tips for how to deploy your application with a variety of tools: Github Pages, Heroku, Surge, and so on. We’ll walk through how to deploy to S3 and CloudFront on AWS.

Check out the following articles.

- [Deploying create-react-app to S3 and CloudFront](https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af)
- [Deploying a React app to S3](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/deploying-a-react-app-to-s3/)
- [Can I deploy my ReactJS app on a regular host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594500/can-i-deploy-my-reactjs-app-on-a-regular-host)
- [How to host static React apps in the Google Storage Bucket behind Cloudflare CDN](https://www.ackee.cz/blog/en/how-to-host-static-react-apps-in-google-storage-bucket-behind-cloudflare-cdn/)
- [Deploying React App on Firebase](https://gautamthapar.me/deploying-react-app-firebase/)

**Check [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mushfiqweb/react-firebase-crud). It shows how to use firebase as hosting and use of firebase real time database.**