# How to Deploy React app on Regular server without build command

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, digital-ocean, netlify

I want to Deploy my react site to the regular server without build command

without `Netlify` or `DigitalOcean`, `Heroku`, `GitHub Pages`, `aws`

Is there a way to run modular bundlers like `Webpack` on Host?

actually what `Netlify` or `DigitalOcean`, `Heroku`, `GitHub Pages`, `aws` doing for show webpage without `npm run build` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594500/can-i-deploy-my-reactjs-app-on-a-regular-host

Comment: But you have to build your website...to minimize assets and ultimately serve it out. You could always built it locally, and then upload the dist folder to your server afterwards.

Comment: why don't you want to run `npm run build` ? Do you not want to run it anywhere, or not run it on the host?

Comment: what is regular server? ngnix? node server ?